# how to manipulate file name using shell scripting

Tags: bash, ubuntu

My source file is located in  `/user/public/test.txt`

The file `test.txt` should be modified to `user_test.txt` and copied to `/home/home/user_test.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative interpretation of the question:

```
file=/usr/public/test.txt
base=user_$(basename $file)
dirn=$(dirname $file)

mv $file $dirn/$base
cp $dirn/$base /home/home/$base
```

Since you stipulate `bash`, the portable code above can use:

```
file=/usr/public/test.txt
base=user_${file##*/}
dirn=${file%/*}

mv $file $dirn/$base
cp $dirn/$base /home/home/$base
```

The code takes liberties because it notes that there are no spaces or newlines or other special characters in the file names.  If you have to deal with those, you have to be a lot more careful (liberal) with the use of double quotes.

Comment: thnks ... it solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
mv /user/public/test.txt /home/home/user_test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`cp` can copy a file under a new name:

```
cp /user/public/test.txt /home/home/user_test.txt
```

If you also want to rename the original file to the new name, you can use `mv`:

```
mv /user/public/test.txt /user/public/user_test.txt
```